# How to convert a string to a number in Vue

Tags: string, vue.js, numbers, int

This string returns the value: `Pressure 770.3157279 mm`

```
<div class="info">Pressure {{info.main.pressure * 0.750064}} mm </div>
```

How do I make the number become an integer and get:
`Pressure 770 mm`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt)

```
<div class="info">Pressure {{ parseInt(info.main.pressure * 0.750064) }} mm </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert any value to an integer, just wrap it into:

```
parseInt(yourValue)
```

You are ready to go.

Comment: "0x20" would parse to 32 and "15e3" to "15000" among others. You have to specify the radix: `parseInt(yourValue, 10)` at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

To convert any value to an integer, just wrap it into:

```
Number(yourValue);
```

Comment: "0x20" would parse to 32 and "15e3" to "15000"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<div class="info">Pressure {{(info.main.pressure * 0.750064).toFixed() }} mm </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code of Vue 2.7, the `v-model.number` modifier casts values to numbers like this:

```
function toNumber(val) {
    var n = parseFloat(val);
    return isNaN(n) ? val : n;
}
```